Issue replicating `calculate_prop` using a custom Rcpp function with `terra::focalCpp`
I’m trying to replicate the behavior of the calculate_prop function from the SpatioTemporalCont package. Specifically, I want to create a custom Rcpp function to calculate the weighted mean of values in a focal window and apply it using terra::focalCpp. However, I’m encountering an error when trying to apply this function through focalCpp.
You can install the SpatioTemporalCont package from GitHub:
remotes::install_github("derek-corcoran-barrios/SpatioTemporalCont")

Here’s a basic example of how the calculate_prop function works:
library(terra)
#;-) terra 1.7.78
library(SpatioTemporalCont)
library(Rcpp)

# Load example dataset (categorical land-use raster)
data("Landuse_DK")
nature <- terra::unwrap(Landuse_DK)

# Calculate proportions for specific land-use categories
proportions <- calculate_prop(Rast = nature, Radius = 200, Vars = c("Agriculture", "Forest"))
#;-) Starting to generate dummy stack [1/3]
#;-) Calculating the weight matrix [2/3]
#;-) Generating final stack [3/3]

# Plot the result
plot(proportions, colNA = "black")


Custom Rcpp Function
I created a custom C++ function to calculate the weighted mean of values in a focal window. It works as expected when called directly in R:
Rcpp::cppFunction("
NumericVector mean_focal(NumericVector x, NumericVector w, size_t ni, size_t nw) {
    NumericVector out(ni);
    size_t center_index = nw / 2;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ni; i++) {
        size_t start = i * nw;
        double sum_vals = 0;
        double sum_weights = 0;
        int count = 0;

        if (NumericVector::is_na(x[start + center_index])) {
            out[i] = NA_REAL;
            continue;
        }

        for (size_t j = 0; j < nw; j++) {
            if (!NumericVector::is_na(x[start + j])) {
                sum_vals += x[start + j] * w[j];
                sum_weights += w[j];
                count++;
            }
        }

        if (count > 0 && sum_weights > 0) {
            out[i] = sum_vals / sum_weights;
        } else {
            out[i] = NA_REAL;
        }
    }
    return out;
}")

# Example data
x <- c(1, 2, NA, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
weights <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
ni <- 1 # Single window
nw <- length(x)

# Direct function call
mean_focal(x, weights, ni, nw)
#;-) [1] 5.25

Error with terra::focalCpp
When I attempt to apply this custom function to a raster using terra::focalCpp, I get the following error:
library(terra)
# Test raster
Rast <- rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 10, vals = runif(100))
dummy_stack <- c(Rast, Rast) # Dummy stack of two layers

# Focal weights
weights <- terra::focalMat(Rast, d = 3, type = "circle")

# Apply the custom function using focalCpp
FinalStack <- terra::focalCpp(dummy_stack, w = weights, fun = mean_focal, fillvalue = NA)
#;-) Error: [focalCpp] test failed

I’ve also tried a simpler function for summing values in the focal window, but it still fails with the same error. Any ideas on how I can successfully use focalCpp with my custom function?
cppFunction("
NumericVector simple_sum(NumericVector x, size_t ni, size_t nw) {
    NumericVector out(ni);
    size_t start = 0;
    size_t center_index = nw / 2;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ni; i++) {
        size_t end = start + nw;
        double sum_vals = 0;

        if (NumericVector::is_na(x[start + center_index])) {
            out[i] = NA_REAL;
        } else {
            for (size_t j = start; j < end; j++) {
                if (!NumericVector::is_na(x[j])) {
                    sum_vals += x[j];
                }
            }
            out[i] = sum_vals;
        }
        start = end;
    }
    return out;
}
")

# Test this simple sum function
FinalStack <- terra::focalCpp(dummy_stack, w = weights, fun = simple_sum, fillvalue = NA)
# ;-)

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated!
Final Goal
Ultimately, the goal is to replicate the behavior of the original calculate_prop function, which calculates the proportion of each land-use category within a given radius around each cell of a raster.


Standard output and standard error

-- nothing to show --




Session info

sessioninfo::session_info()
#;-) ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#;-)  setting  value
#;-)  version  R version 4.4.1 (2024-06-14)
#;-)  os       Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
#;-)  system   x86_64, linux-gnu
#;-)  ui       X11
#;-)  language en_US:en
#;-)  collate  en_US.UTF-8
#;-)  ctype    en_US.UTF-8
#;-)  tz       Europe/Copenhagen
#;-)  date     2024-10-04
#;-)  pandoc   3.1.11 @ /usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/x86_64/ (via rmarkdown)
#;-) 
#;-) ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#;-)  package            * version    date (UTC) lib source
#;-)  cli                  3.6.3      2024-06-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  codetools            0.2-19     2023-02-01 [4] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
#;-)  curl                 5.2.2      2024-08-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  digest               0.6.37     2024-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  evaluate             0.24.0     2024-06-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  fastmap              1.2.0      2024-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  fs                   1.6.4      2024-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  glue                 1.7.0      2024-01-09 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#;-)  highr                0.11       2024-05-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  htmltools            0.5.8.1    2024-04-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  knitr                1.48       2024-07-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  lifecycle            1.0.4      2023-11-07 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#;-)  magrittr             2.0.3      2022-03-30 [3] CRAN (R 4.1.3)
#;-)  purrr                1.0.2      2023-08-10 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.1)
#;-)  R.cache              0.16.0     2022-07-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  R.methodsS3          1.8.2      2022-06-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  R.oo                 1.26.0     2024-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  R.utils              2.12.3     2023-11-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  Rcpp               * 1.0.13     2024-07-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  reprex               2.1.0      2024-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  rlang                1.1.4      2024-06-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  rmarkdown            2.28       2024-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  rstudioapi           0.16.0     2024-03-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  sessioninfo          1.2.2      2021-12-06 [3] CRAN (R 4.1.2)
#;-)  SpatioTemporalCont * 0.0.0.9000 2024-10-04 [1] local
#;-)  styler               1.10.3     2024-04-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  terra              * 1.7-78     2024-05-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
#;-)  vctrs                0.6.5      2023-12-01 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#;-)  withr                3.0.1      2024-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  xfun                 0.47       2024-08-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-)  xml2                 1.3.6      2023-12-04 [3] CRAN (R 4.3.2)
#;-)  yaml                 2.3.10     2024-07-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.1)
#;-) 
#;-)  [1] /home/au687614/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.4
#;-)  [2] /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
#;-)  [3] /usr/lib/R/site-library
#;-)  [4] /usr/lib/R/library
#;-) 
#;-) ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


If you step into the method you'll see that the error is <simpleError in fun(v, ..., ni = 1, nw = msz): argument "w" is missing, with no default> -- note that ... but not w is forwarded. The simplified one seems to work fine? (I don't know what it's supposed to return but at least it's not an error for me) This is all perfectly congruent with the documentation: "The function must have at least three arguments. The first argument can have any name [..] The other two arguments [are] ni  and nw. ... additional arguments to fun".
